# iphone read txt file from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsstring, text-files

I can read the data in file.txt file located in local disk.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* Data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error ];
```

now, I upload the file.txt file into a website. how can i read the data from the txt file now from UIWebView?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The similar way:

```
NSString* Data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileURL usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error ];
```